# Firebase Hosting with Environment Variables?

Tags: firebase, dart, environment-variables, firebase-hosting

My Firebase application has dev & prod environments (two separate Firebase projects).

**Issue**: The config passed to `firebase.initializeApp()` is environment-dependent. Currently, I have this hardcoded. If I want to deploy to dev, I comment-out the initializeApp call with the prod config, and visa versa. Is there anyway to do this intelligently with environment variables? For instance, when I run the commands:

```
firebase use prod
firebase deploy --hosting
```

can 'prod' be passed as an environment variable to the javascript code so it knows to pass the prod-config to `firebase.initializeApp()`?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation about an alternative that's even  better than environment. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration

Comment: What about cloud functions in staging/production? How can I initialize them by environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common development scenario and Angular has you covered.  Beyond Firebase there are probably other options you may want to change depending on whether you are testing/deploying in development or production.

Check out the Angular docs for [Building and serving Angular apps](https://angular.io/guide/build). This has all the info detailing the usage of this.

They make use of an environment.ts file, which most likely would include your Firebase *development* config, and an environment.prod.ts file, which would include your Firebase *production* config.

In your angular.json file you detail the configuration options where if you are building with a production option it would replace the environment.ts file with your envionrment.prod.ts file.

When using `ng build` it would use your dev config. When ready to test and deploy your app you would add a configuration switch, such as `ng build --configuration=production`